# Entity Framewok: Is it possible to duplicate an entity and create an alias for it?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

In my model, I have a [Customer] table with a self-assocation as:

1 [Customer] may have 1 [Sponsor], and Sponsors are Customers.

[image]

In EF 6, I want to know if it's possible to split the entity Customer in two separate entities [Customer] and [Sponsor] and assign them the same table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit entities to make an alias consider this example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    // your shared properties here
}

public class Customer: Person
{
    // additional properties such as
    public virtual Sponsor Sponsor {get;set;} 
}

public class Sponsor : Person
{
    // this could be have own properties or not
}
```

Now your `DbContext` could be something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Person> Persons{get;set;}
    // optionally you could add child objects
    public IDbSet<Customer> Customers{get;set;}
    public IDbSet<Sponsor> Sponsors{get;set;}
}
```

Because of using inheritance `EF` just create one table for your Entities. But you have 3 separate class.

Comment: Am I obliged to create the entity Person? I want to have Customer as root category only.

Comment: No it is just an example. You can have just 2 entity an inherit one from another. In this case you can omit the person entity and inherit sponsor directly from customer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        //all your columns goes here
        ///these 2 lines for foreign key mapping except sponsor
        public virtual Customer Sponsor {get;set;} 
        public virtual IList<Customer> CustomerList{get;set;}
    }
```

in your DbContext

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers{get;set;}
```